# Creating a Virtual Webcam Device for OS X

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webcam

I am looking for a solution to create a "virtual" webcam device under OS X (that acts just as a normal hardware webcam, but the application has full control over what to output). I'm fairly experienced with C++, but not so much with Objective-C and OSX/Cocoa programming.

Anyone that can point me in the right direction, where to look and what I should be looking for? I've searched, but most of the results seems to focus on Windows and DirectX.

Thanks!

Comment: Wondered the same thing. I'm guessing lots of people would like to "cheat" at Chatroulette. ;-)

Comment: Haha :) I think it's kind of strange though since I can't find any good information about it. But maybe I'm just looking in the wrong places. Still looking, and I found this, maybe useful: http://gemma.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/ImageCaptureDeviceModulesReference/index.html

Comment: I've found a couple of links that could be interesting for anyone in the same situation as me (I haven't been able to solve the problem yet, but I'm still looking into it):
http://lists.apple.com/archives/usb/2002/Sep/msg00045.html
http://lists.apple.com/archives/darwin-development/2001/Jul/msg00357.html

Comment: Can you go into more detail what you want this for? I could think of several alternatives, but it really depends on what you're doing. What application(s) are supposed to use the video from this virtual webcam? Your own? Third party? iChat? What video will it provide? File contents? Algorithmically generated? ... ?

Comment: I'm interested in this in order to send video with Syphon into the web browser using the WebRTC apis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to go is to use [CoreMediaIO](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/CoreMediaIO/Introduction/Intro.html) framework. You can create a virtual device using the framework.

Answer (score 3):

To get started you should have a look at http://webcam-osx.sourceforge.net/
It is an opensource webcam driver kit for os x.

Answer (score -2):

For an example I would try decompiling or finding a open source virtual webcam

Try this program: http://download.b-l-a-c-k-o-p.com/?m=0

Check out http://www.hopperapp.com/ for a decompiler

Comment: I'm afraid of be affected in your link...