# Modifying a webcam stream

Tags: opencv, virtual, webcam, gstreamer

Currently I'm working on a project where I need to modify a webcam stream that is streaming to skype. Essentially I want to do things like blur the face and do other anonymizing techniques.

While doing this project however I've been having several issues. Firstly I was using opencv to do the modifications, which was starting to work out well until i tried to interface this with skype (which it wouldnt since opencv takes over the webcam and then skype cannot use it). I then was directed to the GStreamer libraries by a friend which seems like they could work, but I kept getting errors which no one else seemed to be receiving. At the moment I am looking into DirectShow. I have been able to make a virtual webcam for skype to see, but the virtual webcam only takes input from a file. Im working in Windows and/or Linux, depending on which i make more progress in.

So i essentially have 2 questions

1. If you have done a project or something similar to what I am doing, could you tell me how you went about doing it
2. Since I'm still working with Gstreamer+Opencv and Directshow methods, does anyone know how to give input from opencv or other webcam into the virtual webcam (I have looked at input pins for the virtual webcam but do not understand how to use them)

Also, yes I have searched for an answer, but as these were a steep learning curve for me, and most answers being non code, I was getting quite confused with some of the answers.

Comment: which errors did you keep getting with gstreamer that no one else got ?

Comment: these were the errors when running just basic-tutorial1.c from the gstreamer.com sdk in windows.

Comment: (basic-tutorial-1.exe:29092): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_set_state: asse
rtion `GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed

(basic-tutorial-1.exe:29092): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_get_bus: assert
ion `GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed

(basic-tutorial-1.exe:29092): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered:
 assertion `GST_IS_BUS (bus)' failed

(basic-tutorial-1.exe:29092): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_object_unref: assertion
 `object != NULL' failed

(basic-tutorial-1.exe:29092): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_set_state: asse
rtion `GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed

Comment: Sorry been quite busy with things. Those errors are from the  basic-tutorial-1.c from www.gstreamer.com

Comment: For Mac OS X, [check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2538573/176769).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Virtual Webcam Driver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627448/virtual-webcam-driver)

Comment: Or this: [Device driver to act as a virtual web camera](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079165/device-driver-to-act-as-a-virtual-web-camera)

Answer (score 0):

on linux, gstreamer provides a "v4l2sink" element, that allows you to write a video-stream into a [v4l2loopback](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback) device, which can be opened by (some versions of) skype (skype's v4l2 support is quite broken)