# Are MacOS Virtual Webcams inherently incompatible with 10.14's Hardened Runtime Library Validation?

Tags: macos, security, webcam, core-media

## Initial Observation

Zoom for Mac [4.6.9](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/201361963-New-Updates-for-macOS), which addresses [scary security flaws](https://objective-see.com/blog/blog_0x56.html), removes the [disable-library-validation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_security_cs_disable-library-validation?language=objc) entitlement.

With the same release, Snap Camera, a virtual webcam app, [stopped working](https://support.lensstudio.snapchat.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041102572-How-do-I-use-Snap-Camera-with-Zoom-).

## Research

I'm not familiar with the particular APIs you use to build a virtual webcam, but it looks like it involves `CoreMediaIO` plugins:

[Creating a Virtual Webcam Device for OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538573/creating-a-virtual-webcam-device-for-os-x)

```
> otool -L /Library/CoreMediaIO/Plug-Ins/DAL/SnapCamera.plugin/Contents/MacOS/SnapCamera
/Library/CoreMediaIO/Plug-Ins/DAL/SnapCamera.plugin/Contents/MacOS/SnapCamera:
    libSnapCamera.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 1452.23.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/Versions/A/CoreMedia (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMediaIO.framework/Versions/A/CoreMediaIO (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Versions/A/CoreVideo (compatibility version 1.2.0, current version 1.5.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation (compatibility version 300.0.0, current version 1452.23.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 275.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/Versions/A/IOSurface (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 400.9.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.50.4)
```

Out of curiosity, I tried a couple other virtual webcams -- [Iriun Webcam](https://iriun.com/) and [EpocCam](http://www.kinoni.com/epoccam_support.html) –- and they behave similarly. Both have CoreMediaIO plugins, and neither works with recent Zoom.

All three virtual cameras work in Microsoft Teams, which has the entitlement:

```
> codesign -d --entitlements :- /Applications/Microsoft\ Teams.app/ |grep valid
Executable=/Applications/Microsoft Teams.app/Contents/MacOS/Teams
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.disable-library-validation</key>
```

They also work in Google Chrome (on this [test page](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/)). It looks like at least one of Chrome's helpers has the entitlement:

```
codesign -d --entitlements :- /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/Frameworks/Google\ Chrome\ Framework.framework/Versions/81.0.4044.92/Helpers/Google\ Chrome\ Helper\ \(Plugin\).app
Executable=/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Frameworks/Google Chrome Framework.framework/Versions/81.0.4044.92/Helpers/Google Chrome Helper (Plugin).app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome Helper (Plugin)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.disable-library-validation</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I've also noticed that the plugin appears in Activity Monitor's *Open Files and Ports* for a couple processes belonging to Teams and Chrome. (`/Library/CoreMediaIO/Plug-Ins/DAL/SnapCamera.plugin/Contents/MacOS/SnapCamera`)

## Question

How do CoreMedia Virtual Webcam plugins work, and do they inherently conflict with Library Validation? (e.g., loading a library into the camera-using process in a way that's no longer permitted)

Is it no longer possible to create Virtual Webcams on MacOS without running afoul of Hardened Runtime?

---

Update 4/19: Zoom's [changelog](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/201361963-New-Updates-for-macOS) for 4.6.10 now says *"Zoom has temporarily removed virtual camera support."*. It'll be interesting see see if/how they reenable it. (perhaps limiting the entitlement to a helper process that's only used when needed?)

Comment: very interesting analysis, I myself are looking into how to register a virtual camera to the system to make my own SnapCamera app equivalent. But boy.. there is ZERO documentation or examples.

Comment: Apparently you can `codesign --remove-signature /Applications/zoom.us.app` to disable library validation, and virtual cams again show up. (via https://www.reddit.com/r/VIDEOENGINEERING/comments/fy7xi3/fyi_zoom_v4610_breaks_blackmagic_capture_devices/ )

Comment: I notice this is no longer a problem. I wonder what changed. `disable-library-validation` has not been added back.

Comment: Specifically, it looks to be fixed May 2020 from the change log you linked. I added a new question to understand how they did this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72538477/how-do-zoom-and-chrome-allow-for-virtual-webcams-without-com-apple-security-cs-d

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with Microsoft Skype for MacOS (8.61.0.95) on Catalina 10.15.5

I was able to fix  this by going to

> `cd /Applications/Skype.app/Contents/Frameworks`

and then removing the signatures for ***all*** the .app parts of Skype, i.e.

`codesign --remove-signature Skype\ Helper.app`

`codesign --remove-signature Skype\ Helper\ \(GPU\).app`

`codesign --remove-signature Skype\ Helper\ \(Plugin\).app`

`codesign --remove-signature Skype\ Helper\ \(Renderer\).app`

Afterwards, restart Skype.

Now in the Settings, when you select the Camera, you should see CamTwist and CamTwist (2VUY) appear.

Similar fix works with zoom:

`codesign --remove-signature /Applications/zoom.us.app\`

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with Teams and EpocCamHD; three components you have to remove code signing from:

```
sudo codesign --remove-signature /Applications/Microsoft\ Teams.app

sudo codesign --remove-signature /Applications/Microsoft\ Teams.app/Contents/MacOS/Teams

sudo codesign --remove-signature /Applications/Microsoft Teams.app/Contents/Frameworks/Microsoft\ Teams\ Helper.app
```

Answer (score 0):

To restore ecamm.com iGlasses virtual cam functionality in MS Teams, had previously removed just this code signature:

sudo codesign --remove-signature /Applications/Microsoft Teams.app/Contents/Frameworks/Microsoft\ Teams\ Helper.app

as per: https://support.ecamm.com/en/articles/4343963-virtual-camera-missing-after-microsoft-teams-update

But with latest (MacOS 10.15.7, MS Teams 1.00.326266), in my case, I found that removing two more code signatures, as per https://stackoverflow.com/users/14049551/tatorpitt, was necessary before iGlasses functionality was restored:

sudo codesign --remove-signature /Applications/Microsoft\ Teams.app

sudo codesign --remove-signature /Applications/Microsoft\ Teams.app/Contents/MacOS/Teams