# Virtual Cameras such as Ecamm Live not showing up in notarized mac electron app

Tags: macos, electron, chromium

I have built an electron app that uses the camera, via `getUserMedia`. When I build the app in the development environment (with the `electron` cmd), the Ecamm Live virtual camera works fine. However, when I build for production with electron-builder (with hardened runtime and notarization), Ecamm Live no longer shows up in the production app. I am building and testing in macOS.

I am using `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()` to list the devices. Other physical cameras work in the production app, just not virtual cameras such as Ecamm Live.

Any idea what's going on? I have upgraded the Electron version to 9.1.0, as I had read that there were some changes in Chrome >80 that might affect this, but that didn't help. FWIW, the camera appears fine in my Chrome app.

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out, with some clues from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61114738/are-macos-virtual-webcams-inherently-incompatible-with-10-14s-hardened-runtime).

To get virtual cameras to work in a notarized, hardened runtime app (I believe this also applies to fully native mac apps), you need to disable library validation with the `com.apple.security.cs.disable-library-validation` entitlement.

Once I added that entitlement and rebuilt the electron app, virtual cameras worked as expected.