# How do Zoom and Chrome allow for Virtual Webcams without com.apple.security.cs.disable-library-validation?

Tags: macos, security, webcam, core-media

This is a continuation of a previous question asked a few years ago: [Are MacOS Virtual Webcams inherently incompatible with 10.14's Hardened Runtime Library Validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61114738/are-macos-virtual-webcams-inherently-incompatible-with-10-14s-hardened-runtime)

I notice that above question has become outdated. Zoom works fine with virtual webcams even though these are the entitlements:
[image]

What is Zoom doing to allow for virtual webcams? I'd like to do this in my own application but I need the `com.apple.security.cs.disable-library-validation` entitlement to allow for virtual webcams.

Fwiw Chrome also does not have this, though Loom and Firefox do.

Looks like it was [re-enabled/fixed May 2020](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/201361963-New-Updates-for-macOS):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what's happening is there is a "plugin" or sub-app that has this permission enabled in Zoom. The app for Zoom is called "caphost".

[image]

You can see Cr-related code here that allows for this entitlement here:
[helper-plugin-entitlements.plist](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:chrome/app/helper-plugin-entitlements.plist;l=7?q=chrome%2Fapp%2Fhelper-plugin-entitlements.plist&ss=chromium%2Fchromium%2Fsrc)

Comment: Fantastic find! I'd been wondering this myself. I notice there's some kind of new camera plugin offering in WWDC 2022 that presumably fixes this. p.s. please accept your answer